# .net core Ftp commands doesn't work and raises no error on my production server

Tags: c#, .net-core, ftp

I have a c# .netcore 2.2 console application to test ftp commands.
It works perfectly on my dev machine but it doesn't on my production server.
The ftp command is executed but it happens nothing and no errors are raised.

Here is the dotnet version installed on my production server :
[image]

Here is the code of my app

```
    class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new FtpServerConfiguration
        {
            Login = "badlogin", 
            Password = "abcd1234", 
            Server = "ftp.myserver.com" 
        };

        Console.WriteLine("First Attempt with bad login");
        var results = await GetFileList(config, "");

        Console.WriteLine("\nSecond Attempt with good login");
        config.Login = "goodlogin";
        results = await GetFileList(config, "");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetFileList(FtpServerConfiguration config, string remoteDir)
    {
        IList<string> files = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            var request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Concat("ftp://", config.Server, "/", remoteDir));
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
            request.UseBinary = true;
            request.UsePassive = config.UsePassive;
            request.EnableSsl = false;
            request.Timeout = config.Timeout;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(config.Login, config.Password);

            Console.WriteLine("send command");
            using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("response received");
                var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                string line = reader.ReadLine();
                while (line != null)
                {
                    files.Add(line);
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Files :");
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t" + file);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: "+ex.Message);
        }

        return files;
    }
}
public class FtpServerConfiguration
{
    public string Server { get; set; }

    public string Login { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool UsePassive { get; set; }

    public int Timeout { get; set; } = 10000;
}
```

---

I query the same FTP server with the same credentials from the 2 machines and here are the results on my dev machine
[image]

and then on my production server

[image]

Does anybody have an idea of what's going on ?
Thank you

Comment: How do you know that the default folder on the production server has any files to list? Or that your login has permission to see them?

Comment: The images links do not work.

Comment: Can you list that directory using any (standalone, GUI) FTP client running on the production server?

Comment: I query the same ftp server with the same credentials from my dev machine or production server

Comment: @MartinPrikryl : Yes, if on my production server, I use my browser (Firefox) to connect to ftp : // ftp.myserver.com it works perfectly

Comment: Show us a log file for that.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Which logs do you want ?

Comment: FTP protocol logs, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @MartinPrikryl
By watching FTP logs I saw the difference between the calls from the 2 machines.

So I try a new call adding UsePassive=true and now it works from the 2 machines.

The only thing I can't explain is "Why it doesn't generate any errors ?"

Comment: Did you wait long enough? It most probably raises timeout exception after a while.